# How to use two functions in onClick in Framer Motion ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I can't understand why I can't pass those two functions in onClick event in my ParsedColors Component. Only one is running. And if I change the places of the functions, the other one is running only.

Here are the functions:

```
const ParsedColors = props => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState('');

    const handleClick = ([color, productId]) => {
        setColor([productId, color])
        setSelected(color)
    }
    
    return(
        <AnimateSharedLayout>
            <ul>
                {props.product.color.map(color => {
                    const parsed = JSON.parse(color)
                    return(
                        <Color
                            key={parsed.value}
                            color={parsed.value}
                            isSelected={selected === parsed.value}
                            onClick={() => handleClick([parsed.value, props.product._id])}
                        />
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        </AnimateSharedLayout>
    )
}
  
  const Color = ({ color, isSelected, onClick }) => {
    return (
      <li className="item" onClick={onClick} style={{ backgroundColor: color}}>
        {isSelected && (
          <motion.div
            layoutId="outline"
            className="outline"
            initial={false}
            animate={{ borderColor: color }}
            transition={spring}
          />
        )}
      </li>
    );
  }

const spring = {
    type: "spring",
    stiffness: 500,
    damping: 30
  };
```

Here is where I use the component:

```
<div className="product--Card--Layout">
    <div className="product--Colors--Container">
       <ParsedColors product={product}/>
    </div>
...
```

Comment: declare a function named `handleClick`, invoke those two function into this function. Finally, change that onClick to `onClick={handleClick}`. Run the code and see if it works or not.

Comment: no, only one function is running again

Comment: actually, I can't declare it outside cuz the second function is updating a state in component ParsedColors. I saw what u mean, but In my case it wont work

Comment: Creating a `handleClick` function should work, and likely has the same issue. How are you verifying one function, or the other, isn't being called? Why can't `setColor` be called directly in the callback... all `colorPicker` does is proxy the `[productId, colors]` value.

Comment: Can you check my updated question? Is it that what you mean before ?

Comment: And you are right about setColor I didn't saw it

Comment: If that is what you mean in my updated question it doesn't work. Only the setColor function is running for some reason

Comment: Are you saying then that your `selected` state isn't updating via `setSelected(color)`? If so, again, how are you verifying/validating this?

Comment: Yes, if setSelected is in onClick event and is only function, it update the selected, but now it doesn't. The selected stays empty string. I just console.log it on click.

Comment: I doubt it's not updating. Is `color` the value you expect it to be in the callback? If you are console logging right after calling `setColor` this doesn't work as React state updates are asynchronously processed.

Comment: yes the color is the value I expect, the second funcion setColor is working fine. I'm using it there too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233205/discussion-between-yollo-and-drew-reese).